# Pytorch - mass classification

Tags: pytorch

I trained a model to classify picture into 2 classes.

I wanna use it to order my iPhone images, I have got a lot. So I moved the trained model on my MacBook and started some tests.

Everything works as expected as long a the image folder contains not more than 223 pictures.

It seems to have something to do with the size of the dataset, I can reproduce the issue with the following code.

I tried to split the pictures into batches but I could not figure out how. What is the common fix to that issue? Is it possible to use a Dataloader?

```py
test_dataset = ImageFolderWithPaths('/Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/', test_trans)
 
# check images
for img, label, data in test_dataset:
     print(img.shape, label, data)
     data_path = '/Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/'
     data_path = '/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/'
     data_file = data.split('/')[-1]
     data_file_new = 'class0_' + data.split('/')[-1]
     print(data_path + data_file_new)
```

## Output

```
torch.Size([3, 64, 64]) 0 /Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/3/020B1786-E77D-47E8-B0F1-DD72313546B7.jpeg
/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/class0_020B1786-E77D-47E8-B0F1-DD72313546B7.jpeg

torch.Size([3, 64, 64]) 0 /Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/3/020BC6D0-2AC0-4BF3-A540-6630BA7200ED.jpeg
/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/class0_020BC6D0-2AC0-4BF3-A540-6630BA7200ED.jpeg
torch.Size([3, 64, 64]) 0 /Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/3/021453CC-CAC1-4546-8188-20739F3C778F.jpeg
/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/class0_021453CC-CAC1-4546-8188-20739F3C778F.jpeg
torch.Size([3, 64, 64]) 0 /Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/3/0235EEF0-2831-46D3-8889-8E57CDF42205.jpeg
/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/class0_0235EEF0-2831-46D3-8889-8E57CDF42205.jpeg
torch.Size([3, 64, 64]) 0 /Users/daniel/Gimp/test-ds/test/3/02398B72-6F73-49D6-843B-25E2A2593DA9.jpeg
/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/class0_02398B72-6F73-49D6-843B-25E2A2593DA9.jpeg
```

## Prediction Method

```
class pred01():
  def __init__(self, imgpath, model):
    cc = 0
    cc1 = 0
    cc0 = 0
    cc2 = 0
    """Predict image class"""
    self.ds = ImageFolderWithPaths(imgpath, transform=test_trans)
    for img, label, data in self.ds:
        self.xb = to_device(img.unsqueeze(0), device)
        self.yb = model(self.xb)
        _, self.preds = torch.max(self.yb, dim=1)
        self.preds1 = torch.softmax(self.yb, dim=1).max()
        cc += 1
        if dataset.classes[self.preds[0].item()] == '0' and self.preds1.item() > 0.80 or self.preds1.item() == 1.00:
            #print('normal pic')
            cc0 += 1
        #    pass
        elif dataset.classes[self.preds[0].item()] == '1' and self.preds1.item() > 0.80 or self.preds1.item() == 1.00:
            #print('class pic, new name: ' 'class1_' + data.split('/')[-1])
            #os.rename(data, '/Users/daniel/Pictures/Photos1/1/' + 'duolingo_' + data.split('/')[-1])
            cc1 += 1
        else:
            pass
            #print('not sure')
            cc2 += 1
    print(cc)
    print(f'cc0: {cc0}')
    print(f'cc1: {cc1}')
    print(f'cc2: {cc2}')
```

## Results after 3 runs

```
365
cc0: 152
cc1: 195
cc2: 18

365
cc0: 154
cc1: 186
cc2: 25

365
cc0: 136
cc1: 206
cc2: 23
```

Comment: What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: I found the mistake, an open temp file inside the image folder broke the script process. After the file has been deleted, it's running till end with over 350 pix. One thing I notice is that the probability and prediction is different with every run.
I added the check script with predictions above. What can I do in order to make the result more consistent?